# Which Werewolf movie was the first to describe what would happen if a person was bitten or scratched by a werewolf in human form?

Tags: history-of, werewolf

Which Werewolf movie was the first to describe what would happen if a person was bitten or scratched by a werewolf in human form?

Every werewolf movie describes the effects of being attacked by a werewolf and injured during a full moon.

Which movie was the first to address what happens to somebody if they are injured by a werewolf inbetween full moons?

Comment: Given that werewolf books predate werewolf films by more than 5000 years, your question is a two parter.

Comment: And the book part of the question is a myth question, not fantasy fiction (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lycaon_of_Arcadia)

Comment: False premise.  Werewolves existed in folktales and legends for millennia with their being NO connection between them and the moon, and furthermore, they were not created by being injured by other werewolves.  What happened was that you were torn to pieces unless you managed to escape.

Comment: Maybe it will be easier for you to answer it now.

Comment: somewhat related is that much of what we consider werewolf lore was created by the writer Curt Siodmak.

Answer (score 4):

The first instance of a werewolf bite causing the victim to become a werewolf appears to be the 1935 classic [*Werewolf of London*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werewolf_of_London).

> *"At this very moment here are two cases of werewolfery known to me."*
>
> *"And how did these unfortunate gentlemen contract this medieval unpleasantness?"*
>
> ***"From the bite of another werewolf."***

The small number of werewolf films produced prior to this ([*The Werewolf* (1913)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Werewolf_(1913_film)), The *White Hunter* (1914), *Le Loup Garou* (1923), [*Wolf Blood* (1925)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf_Blood), and [*Haunted People* (1932)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haunted_People) don't seem to have attributed the condition to bites/scratches from other werewolves although the protagonist in *Wolf Blood* does develop wolf-like characteristics as a result of receiving a transfusion of blood from a wolf.

Comment: i coincidentally just read that this movie Werewolf of London was the first to show a bipedal werewolf. if werewolves literally looked like wolves, a lot of the scariness goes away. American Werewolf in London had I think a quadrupedal werewolf but it did not look like a normal wolf. real wolves were objects of fear as were bears before reliable firearms  were available.

Comment: @releseabe Curiously the name "bear" may actually be a [euphemism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bear#Etymology) for the original name of the animal because of fear that speaking the original name would cause it to appear.  I recently encountered this theory when reading [this question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26494/4251) in the Spanish.SE as to why the Spanish word for fox (zorro) doesn't follow from the Latin (vulpés)

Comment: @releseabe An interesting point about "The Wolf Man" 1941 is the gypsy werewolf that bites Lon Chaney Jr. Is a fully transformed into wolf mythological version werewolf.